# socket programming in class

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets

I use below code for socket programing.
it works where i open socket when user click on button but when i move this code to a class and call a method doesn't work

```
CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"IP", Port, &readStream, &writeStream);
    inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
    outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];
    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];
....
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent...
....
```

move to class and call it like below

```
Class1 *cl=[[Class1 alloc]init];
[cl openSocket];
```

Comment: leave Xcode tag alone. It's for IDE specific problem.

Comment: Did the streams opened correctly (in the `stream:handleEvent:`)?

Comment: Yes,when i open socket behind of button click

Comment: What do you mean "behind" of button click"? Is `cl` a local variable?

Comment: when user click on button . cl is object of Class1